# How to compare text box string to int

Tags: c#, .net

I can't get the string of `text_box.text` to convert to an `int` then compare to another `int`.

I also need to check to see if the string of `text_box.text` can be turned into an `int`.

I've tried `.ToInt32`, which I have always used and it has been fine. I have no idea how to test if the string of `text_box` can be turned into an `int`.

```py
public static void before (int bS)
{
    beforeScore = bS;
}

//some space later

if (score_bet_text_box.Text.ToInt32() > beforeScore)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You can't bet more than you have", "game");
}
```

I expect it to convert the string of `text_box` into an `int`, then compare it to the other `int`.

I also hope to test if it can be converted into an `int`, but have no clue how so it is not shown in the code above.

Comment: TextBox.Text is just a string. It does _not_ have a `ToInt32()` method. Look into the [`Int32.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse) and [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) methods. You use the former one when you're certain the string is, in fact, convertible to `Int32` and you use the latter when you're not certain which seems to be the case.

Comment: Use Int32.TryParse(). You can find a lot of examples here on StackOverflow

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: it would be a nice extension method though ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToInt32` isn't a method on a string unless you have an extension method somewhere. You want to use the `TryParse` method as follows...

```
if(int.TryParse(score_bet_text_box.Text, out int result))
{
    if(result > beforeScore)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You can't bet more than you have", "game");
    }
}
```

If you are using an older version of C# you'll have to define result outside the if as follows:

```
int result;
if(int.TryParse(score_bet_text_box.Text, out result))
```